# Pagination for angular material table with a tree

Tags: arrays, angular, pagination, angular-material, treeview

I have to implement a table with tree. This part is done and you can find an example about the code here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m77g7e-semvxp?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

But I didn't find a way for using the material component mat-paginator because the class MatTreeFlatDataSource doesnt' have property for that.

Does anyone have an idea about how to do the pagination control?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this eventually? Like a custom paginator maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I used a normal MatTableDataSource for paging to only hand MatTreeFlatDataSource the current page:

```
this.dataSource['_renderData'].subscribe((treeNodes: TreeNode<T>[]) => {
    this.flatDataSource.data = treeNodes;
});
```